# URL issue while migrating website from root domain to sub directory

Tags: html, .htaccess, yii, url-rewriting, craftcms

I have a situation as follows:
I have a website with lots of files in it (Yii Framework). I need to migrate it from http://domain1.com to http://domain2.com/foo/bar/

But previous developer has put the `href, src, background-image` etc links as follows:
`href="/assets/img/img1.jpg"
src="/assets/js/script.js"`

When I open the new website in browser, all the resources should be loaded like this http://domain2.com/foo/bar/assets/... to make it work. But, browser is interpreting the resources url as http://domain2.com/assets/...
As the resources doesn't exists here, they aren't loading.

As the urls are scattered everywhere in lots of files, it's not the best idea to change each and every url.

Is there a way to change the base url through htaccess (or some other method) so that server or browser will interpret `href="/assets/..."` as `http://domain2.com/foo/bar/assets/...`

Answer (score 0):

You may use this `301` redirect rule at the top of other rules:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?domain1\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^assets/.+ http://domain2.com/foo/bar%{REQUEST_URI} [L,NC,NE,R=301]
```